# Wrong output for date format in Grails

Tags: java, grails, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a `Date` in Grails, here is my code in the controller:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
empRefInstance.startDate=sdf.parse(params.startDate)
empRefInstance.endDate=sdf.parse(params.endDate) 
println ("dates " + empRefInstance.startDate +" "+empRefInstance.endDate)
```

the output supposed to be `01-05-2016` as per the format i defined  but the output of the both date in this format

```
Sun May 01 00:00:00 EEST 2016
```

is there something wrong in the formater?

Comment: How are you getting that output? You're not including that in your question.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore i edited the question

Comment: Is it safe to assume then that `startDate` and `endDate` are both `Date` data types? If so then this is expected default behavior for what a `Date` outputs when it's not formatted. If you want to display it in a particular format you can use the `.format()` method. Like this: `empRefInstance.startDate.format('dd-MM-yyyy')`

Answer (score 0):

You are not formatting the output instead you have only parsed.

> **Formatting**: Converting the `Date` to `String` (the `format` method)
>   **Parsing**: Converting the `String` to `Date` (the `parse` method)

To format, you need to do like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
// First you are converting the incoming date string to a date
empRefInstance.startDate = sdf.parse(params.startDate)
empRefInstance.endDate=sdf.parse(params.endDate)

// Now we have to conert the date object to string and print it
println ("dates " + sdf.format(empRefInstance.startDate) + " "+sdf.format(empRefInstance.endDate))
```

When you print a `Date` object in Groovy/Java, it's default implementation of `toString()` will be invoked hence you were getting output like `Sun May 01 00:00:00 EEST 2016`

Also, Groovy adds a `format` method in `Date` class to direct allow formatting. You can even use that as well.

```
println("dates " + empRefInstance.startDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy") + " " + empRefInstance.endDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the formatter. You're not using one for the output. Something like this will give you the expected output:

`println empRefInstance.startDate.format('dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: when i try `empRefInstance.startDate = sdf.format(sdf.parse(params.startDate))` i got `Cannot cast object '01-05-2016' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'`

Comment: That's because you are trying to set a `Date` to the value of a `String`. Which makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to accomplish by doing that? Your question was about how to get a date to format properly on output, yet your comment is dealing with setting (input).

Comment: What i'm trying to do is i got Date startDate and endDate in my domain , and the return of these field from the view are String so i want to convert the string to date and set it to `empRefInstance.starDate` with the format `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: Your approach is flawed then. You can't specify the format for output when you are setting the value. You have to format the output when you display the output. Just like my answer demonstrates.